# How do I get the pingable IPv6 address of my machine?

Tags: linux, networking, ipv6

when I try:
`$ ip -6 addr` 
I get something like:

`inet6 fe80::d773:9cf0:b0fd:572d/64 scope link`

if I try to ping that from the machine itself:

```
$ ping6 fe80::d773:9cf0:b0fd:572d/64
unknown host

$ ping6 fe80::d773:9cf0:b0fd:572d
connect: Invalid argument
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From `man ping6`, you must tell ping which interface you are using:

> -I interface address
>
> Set source address to specified interface address. Argument may be numeric IP address or name of device. When pinging IPv6 link-local address this option is required.

For example, if your interface is `eth0`:

```
ping6 -I eth0 fe80::xxxxxx
```

or, without the `-I` option:

```
ping6 fe80:xxxxxx%eth0
```

Answer (score 33):

Any IPv6 address that starts with `fe80:` is the equivalent of IPv4 `169.254.*.*` address, i.e. it's a link-local address, reachable only in the network segment it's directly connected to, using the NIC that connects to that segment specifically. Unlike IPv4, however, it is perfectly normal for a NIC to have both the link-local IPv6 address *and* one or more global IPv6 addresses simultaneously.

Since a `fe80:` IPv6 address is link-local, you must specify the network interface you want to use when pinging it.

Example:

```
$ ping6 fe80::beae:c5ff:febe:a742
connect: Invalid argument

$ ping6 -I eth0 fe80::beae:c5ff:febe:a742
PING fe80::beae:c5ff:febe:a742(fe80::beae:c5ff:febe:a742) from fe80::beae:c5ff:febe:a742%eth0 eth0: 56 data bytes
64 bytes from fe80::beae:c5ff:febe:a742%eth0: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.182 ms
64 bytes from fe80::beae:c5ff:febe:a742%eth0: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.167 ms
...
```

You can also append the interface at the end of the address by using the `%` sign: `ping6 fe80::beae:c5ff:febe:a742%eth0`.

This requirement is only for link-local IPv6 addresses: you can ping globally routable IPv6 addresses without specifying the interface.

```
$ ping6 2a00:1450:400f:80a::200e  # that's ipv6.google.com
PING 2a00:1450:400f:80a::200e(2a00:1450:400f:80a::200e) 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 2a00:1450:400f:80a::200e: icmp_seq=1 ttl=55 time=17.6 ms
64 bytes from 2a00:1450:400f:80a::200e: icmp_seq=2 ttl=55 time=19.6 ms
...
```

Comment: It also says `scope link` right in the output :)

Comment: Just as an appendix to the answer: your can also specify the interface at the end of the address: `ping6 fe80::beae:c5ff:febe:a742%eth0`

Comment: @Ferrybig: thanks for reminding me, updated my answer.

Comment: Note that if you want to ping a remote ipv6 address, your home router also has to support ipv6. Older routers do not always have the software/firmware update to support a connection over ipv6. You will most likely get the following message: `ping6: UDP connect: No route to host`